# Vasicek Bond Price/Yield Simulation in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find the linear relationship between bond yield and initial short rate. I am using 48 periods per year and a 13 year bond. My code is as follows:

```
## generate initial short rate matrix
totalcases<-71
r0 <-matrix(nrow=totalcases,ncol=1)
for (i in 1:totalcases){
  if (-.21+i/100 < -.07 ){
    r0[i,1]<- -.21+i/100
  }
  else if (r0[i-1,1] >= .02 ){
    r0[i,1]<- r0[i-1,1]+1/100
  }
  else {
    r0[i,1]<- r0[i-1,1]+.25/100
  }

}

## simulate short rate paths

gamma <- 0.05
sigma <- 0.0135
alpha <- 0.05
lambda <- 0.00

n <- 30000   # MC simulation trials
Time <- 13    # Maturity of the Bond
int <-48 #no of subintervals per year
dt <- 1/int  # difference in time between each subinterval
m <- Time*int   # total subintervals


set.seed(0)
z<-matrix(rnorm(n*m,mean=0,sd=1),nrow=n,ncol=m)

r <- matrix(nrow=n,ncol=m+1)

Yield <-matrix(nrow=totalcases,ncol=1)

for(l in 1:totalcases){

  r[,1]<- r0[l,1]

  for (j in 1:m+1){
    r[,j]<-r[,j-1]*exp(-alpha*dt)+(gamma-(lambda*sigma/alpha))*(1-exp(-alpha*dt))+sigma * sqrt((1 - exp(-2 * alpha *dt)) / (2 * alpha)) *z[,j-1]

  }

  k<-apply(r,1,sum)
  k<-k*dt
  Price<-exp(-k)
  ExptdPrice<-mean(Price)
  Yield[l,1]<- -log(ExptdPrice) / Time

}
```

I have two questions:

1. In the for loop if I loop from 2 to m+1 then my r matrix has all rows except the first one as NAs but when I loop from 1 to m+1 then the matrix is fine. Given that my my first column is fixed (all rows have a fixed value r0) why do I have to run the for loop from 1 to m+1 and not 2 to m+1?
2. My Bond prices are close to the exact solution but not close enough and the accuracy does not increase linearly when I go from 10,000 simulations to 20k or 30k simulations. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. <s>Your call to construct the matrix doesn't give it any initial values, so it starts off as all NA. If you have an initial value in mind, either assign it explicitly with `r0[1] <- <initial_value>`, or include it in the `matrix` call: `matrix(<initial_value>, nrow=71, ncol=1)`. Although since you only have 1 column, you might as well make it a vector.</s> 1:n+1 is parsed as (1:n)+1, not 1:(n+1).
2. The precision of a simulation is typically proportional to the square of the number of trials. If you want double the accuracy, you need 4 times the trials.

Comment: I guess I was not clear with question number 1. My query is regarding the matrix r and not the matrix r0. The for loop in question is the one in the second half of the code.